# PInvokeStackImbalance caused when calling C++ function from VB.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net, dllimport

I'm trying to call a C++ function in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET), and it raises a PInvokeStackImbalance. Here is the C++ function signature:

```
int e1v151(char *NoUsager, char *SequentielSDU, char *code_sys, int code_for, char *IndGest2)
```

And here it is, in VB.NET:

```
DllImport("E1fnbase.dll", EntryPoint:="e1v151", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)>
Public Function e1v151(ByVal NoUsager As String, ByVal SeqSDU As String, ByVal Codesys As String, ByVal CodeFor As Integer, ByVal IndGest2 As String) As Integer
End Function
```

I tried a few things already (using `StringBuilder` instead of `String`, `<MarshalAs(LPStr)­>`) without any success. Is there something I don't see?

Comment: Are you sure that e1v151 uses `cdecl` convention?

Comment: No, but I also tried without any convention (so `StdCall` by default, I think?) and no changes... How do I know which convention is used by e1v151?